# How does one become a DDCA umpire?

Tags: cricket, officiating

I want to know the procedure for applying to be a DDCA umpire and also to be a BCCI umpire?

Comment: Work hard at your craft in the lower umpire ring levels. Do not be confrontational and you will be noticed